# How to properly load page-specific scripts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, build, vite

In Laravel 10, js assets are by default compiled with Vite from /resources/js to /public/build/assets/. And it generate versioned files, meaning that they're like file-987dfdf.js (random string).
In blade templates, the @vite() directive generates correct paths for dev and production modes. But also inject a script that connects to its server for hot module replacement.
Usually @vite is called from the HEAD section of the main layout.

Now, my problem is: how do I load a page-specific scripts from other blade templates (using @stack and @push)? If I use @vite there, then it will inject the server client script again. If I do not use @vite, I have no way to properly reference the build versions of the scripts.

I'm sure there's some smarter way, but can't figure out. Docs do not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your post correctly: It appears you are using @vite and not specifying any files?

Try this instead. In your layout use this where it feels appropriate:

```
@stack('vite')
```

Then in your other blade files where you want to load custom styles or scripts, push to that.

Example:

```
@push('vite')
    @vite(['resources/js/file.ext'])
@endpush
```

With this, you don't need to know the final filename of the resource, only the relative path to it in your resources folder.

Comment: Thank you. But how about global scripts? I mean, usually @vite is used for global scripts. And thus, it already injects its server client. If I use it again via stack, then it will inject the client again.

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion based and I will show the way I do:

Assuming you have these routes

```php
Route::get('/', ...)->name('front');
Route::get('/about', ...)->name('about');
```

1. Define entries per page in `vite.config.ts` (you may set global pattern to auto-discover pages - see accepted answer in [a discussion here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/44578))

```js
// vite.config.js

input: [
    'resources/js/common.js', // common file for every page and backup

    'resources/js/front.js', // front page only
    'resources/js/about.js', // about page only
],
```

1. Create [View composer](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/views#view-composers) class
2. Resolve entrypoint per route (I'm usually naming every possible route - your approach to define which current route is may differ)

```php
// app/View/Composers/EntrypointComposer

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class EntrypointComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view): void
    {
        // "entrypoint" key here is the name of the variable
        // which will be used in a blade file
        $view->with('entrypoint', $this->resolveEntrypointPerPage());
    }

    /**
     * Resolve vite entrypoint
     * based on current route name
     */
    private function resolveEntrypointPerPage(): string|array
    {
        return match (Route::current()->getName()) {
            // On a page named `front` load `common.js` and `front.js`
            'front' => ['resources/js/common.js', 'resources/js/front.js'],

            // You may import `common.js` file within `about.js`
            // Meaning there is no need to add extra point for `common.js`
            'about' => 'resources/js/about.js',

            // etc ...

            // Backup. For non specified pages `common.js` file will be loaded
            default => 'resources/js/common.js',
        };
    }
}
```

4. Register it within ServiceProvider

```php
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function boot()
{
    View::composers([
        EntrypointComposer::class => 'partials.head', // path to the blade component file (**NOT** page) where `@vite` directive is used

        // ...
    ]);
}
```

5. Include key `$entrypoint` in a blade file

```
// partials/head.blade.php

@vite($entrypoint)
```